# Invalid Source when setting HTML5 Video.Src in IE10 using file <Input> with createObjectURL()

Tags: video, input, internet-explorer-10, local-files

Has anybody had this issue with Internet Explorer 10 when setting the src of <video> to a local video file via <input> using createObjectURL() to generate the file path ?

The error: Internet Explorer 10 is giving error 'Invalid Source'.

Sample: I've got a simple html example which works in Chrome v27 and Firefox v21, but NOT in Internet Explorer v10.

Current Workaround: Add domain to IE 10 Trusted sites, then reference "value" of <input> (included my example). But surely the window.URL.createObjectURL() functionality is designed to avoid this workaround. Strangely enough, the <sound> and <img> element works fine in IE 10 using createObjectURL().

Any ideas guys ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Internet Explorer 10 : HTML5 Video.Src : 'Invalid Source' error when setting local file as source using createObjectURL()</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <input type="file" id="filesInputVideo" name="files[]" onchange="handleVideoFileBrowse(event.target)" /> <br />
            <video id="videoElement" width="350" style="border-style: solid" controls></video>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                var createObjectURL = (window.URL && URL.createObjectURL.bind(URL)) ||
                                      (window.webkitURL && webkitURL.createObjectURL.bind(webkitURL)) || 
                                      window.createObjectURL;

                function handleVideoFileBrowse(target) 
                {
                    var url = createObjectURL(target.files[0]); // Works in Chrome v27 and Firefox v21, but NOT in Internet Explorer v10.0.9200

                    //url = target.value; // My temporary workaround for IE 10, but only works if the domain has been added as Trusted in IE: Internet Options - Security - Trusted sites.

                    document.getElementById("videoElement").src = url;
                }
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```